# Put reference for github link at the bottom of a page

Tags: links, hyperlink

I want to put the reference of some code in the bottom of a page as shown in the following example picture,

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: `\footnote{\texttt{}}` does not require any additional package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a footnote and the hyperref package:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

We implement... and make our code available on GitHub.\footnote{\url{https://github.com/ibalazevic/TuckER}}

\end{document}
```

The hyperref package can then accept optional arguments for, say, link colour, whether you want a box, etc.

[image]